# Zermelo's proof for unique factorisation

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

In Peter Bundschuh's "Einführung in die Zahlentheorie" I came across a possibly well-known but to me rather peculiar proof of unique factorisation, which is attributed to Ernst Zermelo. The proof bypasses Euclid's lemma to prove that $ \mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD. It seems to me that the deepest property of the ring of integers used is some properties of the order on $ \mathbb{Z}$! An account of this proof can be seen here:

https://planetmath.org/inductionproofoffundamentaltheoremofarithmetic

Can this idea be applied or has it been applied to any other situations? Or is it simply a tricky proof for the ring of integers?

Comment: Second-last line: "'the prime p is in the prime decomposition of (q-p)⁢c and thus also at least of q-p or c.  But we know that  p∤c, whence  p∣q-p."
Are you using Euclid Lemma here, or am I missing something?

Comment: Since $n_0 < n$, by induction hypothesis $p$ must appear in the unique decomposition of $n_0 = (q-p)c$, which is the product of the unique decompositions of $q-p$ and $c$. It's true that the sentence is quite confusing.

Answer (score 6):

In [Pete Clark's notes on factorization](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/factorization2010.pdf), he calls this the "Lindemann–Zermelo proof" of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and he uses a similar idea to prove the well-known fact that if $R$ is a unique factorization domain, then so is $R[t]$.  See Theorem 27.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the popular textbook by Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery also has a proof of unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$ that is based only on the well-ordering property and that bypasses Euclid's lemma.

The ascending chain condition in the definition of Dedekind domains is used in a similar way to the well-ordering principle in proving unique factorization of ideals in such domains.